# Retrieve azure blob metadata with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, export-to-csv

How do I retrieve the metadata of a blob folder's contents (such as name, size etc) with powershell and export it as CSV?

Comment: Separated into logical steps, removed unnecessary fillers

Comment: Hello, Any update on this issue as per the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have azure powershell [az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.2.0) installed(also you can change the code accordingly if you are using AzureRm module).

There are 2 methods:

**Method 1**: Use PSCustomObject. Sample code as below:

```
    $accountname="xxx"
    $accountkey="xxx"
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountname -StorageAccountKey $accountkey
    $myblobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "aa1" -Context $ctx

    $Output = $myblobs | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Name" = $_.Name
    "Length" =$_.Length
    }
    }

$Output | Export-Csv "d:\temp\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Method 2**: Use psobject. Sample code as below, save the generated file to location "d:\temp\test2.csv":

```
$accountname="xxx"
$accountkey="xxx"
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountname -StorageAccountKey $accountkey
$myblobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "aa1" -Context $ctx

$i=0

foreach($b in $myblobs)
{
$i++

if($i -eq 1)
{
$obj = New-Object psobject
$obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Name" -value $b.name

#the length unit is byte
$obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Length" -value $b.length
 $obj | Export-Csv "d:\temp\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
else
{
$obj = New-Object psobject
$obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Name" -value $b.name
$obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Length" -value $b.length
 $obj | Export-Csv "d:\temp\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}

}
```

Test result as below:

[image]